# Convert a DataType to a UnionAll in Julia

Tags: types, julia

Is it possible to free a `TypeVar` in a `DataType` to get a `UnionAll`?

Big picture, what I am trying to do is:

```
# this doesnt work
f(::Type{V{T}}, ::Type{S}) where {T,S,V<:AbstractVector} = V{S} 

f(Vector{Int}, Char) 
# Vector{Char}
```

My current solution is to `@eval f(::Type{$(V){T}}, S::Type)` for a manually created list of types `V <: AbstractVector`, but I was hoping for a more direct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
function f(::Type{V}, ::Type{S}) where {V<:AbstractVector{T}, S} where T
    s = Core.Compiler.unwrap_unionall(V.name.wrapper)
    v = s.super
    while v.name.wrapper != AbstractArray
        v = v.super
    end
    loc = findfirst(==(v.parameters[1]), s.parameters)
    V.name.wrapper{V.parameters[1:loc-1]...,S,V.parameters[loc+1:end]...}
end
```

And now:

```
julia> f(Vector{Int}, Char)
Array{Char,1}

julia> f(UnitRange{Int}, Float64)
UnitRange{Float64}

julia> abstract type MyType1{A,B,C} <: AbstractVector{B} end

julia> struct MyType2{P,Q,R,S} <: MyType1{R,Q,S} end

julia> f(MyType2{Int, Int, Int, Int}, Char)
MyType2{Int64,Char,Int64,Int64}
```

Note that your approach with `@eval` is not fully general and would not handle complex custom subtypes of `AbstractVector` (as the last one in the example).